# how to avoid "enable JavaScript" response through ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I receive a response "Please enable JavaScript to view the page content."
while I use ajax request, there is a way to avoid that?

**note**
I use ajax inside a "web extensions" code.

[image]

Comment: Using an ajax request for a webpage gets the source of that webpage, it does not execute the javascript that that page uses to load content. You would have to use something like puppeteer or other headless browser library if you wish to fetch js content sites

Answer (score 1):

That's because your response includes a `<noscript>` block, which gets shown if JavaScript isn't enabled. And in the network preview tab, JS is indeed not enabled.

Since end users shouldn't use that tab to visit your site, it shouldn't be something you have to worry about.

Comment: yes, I know but it's not my site I use ajax inside a "chrome extension"  code